# Is it safe to use caret::trainControl in multiple threads?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am using the caret::train function repeatedly to produce many independent models. I have it running in parallel and I was wondering if the caret::trainControl object needed to be created for each iteration of caret::train. Does the caret::train function ever modify the trainControl object, under what circumstances?

In code I guess it could be simplified as...

```
require(caret)

models <- c("mpg ~ wt", "mpg ~ hp")

# Do I have to do this?
for (m in models) {
  tc <- caret::trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=5)
  model <- caret::train(as.formula(m), data=mtcars, trControl=tc, method="lm")
}

# Or can I get away with this
tc <- caret::trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=5)
for (m in models) {
  model <- caret::train(as.formula(m), data=mtcars, trControl=tc, method="lm")
}
```

Obviously, all my train control parameters are the same for each model.

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example? In fact if you had a reproducible example you could just run both options and see it they work.

Comment: I understand that I can test for a specific case but I was wonder in the general case if the caret::trainControl object is ever modified under caret::train. P.S I've still updated my example, thanks!

Comment: I think its considered bad practice if an R function modifies an object present in the environment without it explicitly stating that in the help file. So I am pretty sure the 2nd option is safe.

Comment: For sure @missuse is right. The `trainControl` object is just a list of parameters to be passed to `train`, regardless of the model choice. So you can safely use the 2nd option